# Archive-style page for a custom taxonomy

Tags: wordpress

I've been trying with no luck to use built-in template hierarchy to get a simple page that would list all terms for a custom taxonomy.

I have a custom taxonomy "**editions**" (linked to a custom post type "**courses**").

I have my template that I named "**taxonomy-editions.php**" (also tried *archive-editions.php*) which is called when I try to access a given edition (*/editions/2016* for example, and **archive-editions.php** does the same btw). But whenever I try to access **/editions/**, no template is called (apart from index.php).

Am I doing something wrong here, or is it simply not possible to do that without creating a custom page ? (most of the answers I've found are 2 years old or more).

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the custom taxonomy , then please use the following templates for custom taxonomy and just copy the archive code over this template.

```
taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php
taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php
tag-{slug}.php
tag-{id}.php
category-{slug}.php
category-{ID}.php
```

Also don't forget to use this variables as true when you registering the taxonomy,

```
publicly_queryable=>true
hierarchical=>true
```

You can check the usage of register_taxonomy [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy).

Comment: This doesn't really concern my problem, I'm trying to find a native way (without having to create a custom page) to display all the terms of a custom taxonomy in a page, not the posts having a specific term.